# Git clone fails from makefile

Tags: git, makefile, git-clone

I am on windows and I have to used makefile to clone a repository. So far simplified the case to:

```
TE_GIT=git@gitlab.someserver.com:te/te.git

all:
    git clone --branch $(TE_BRANCH) $(TE_GIT) TranslationEditor
```

running the clone command from cmd or powershell works fine.

running via

`make -f Makefile.test`

produces

**Permission denied (publickey).**

What I checked?

1. my ssh-keys work and are added
2. the same version of ssh is called from cmd and makescript
3. the same command works from powershell script

Can you give me a hint what else I can check, investigate, try?

EDIT: using **nmake** works fine.

Somehow **make** does not use the proper environment.

Comment: make default shell is the Bourne shell. My guess is that the information about your ssh agent is not passed to it correctly when you invoke make from `powershell`. You could try to check this by printing some environment variables from your Makefile (`SSH_AGENT_PID`...).

Comment: @RenaudPacalet, thanks it kind of helped. Apparently via the makefile I am not getting the right credentials. 
Now I have to find out why... 
It seems that somehow makefile and cmd tries to call to different ssh-agents?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, in my case the problem was the location of "HOME".

Apparently nmake uses the windows env variables to search for identity files, "known_hosts" files and similar.

While make tries to search "HOME". If no such env variable it goes to c:\ (thus using c:.ssh...).

To fix it add temporarly or permanently (it is up to you):

Powershell:`$env:home = $env:userprofile`
cmd: `set(x) HOME *path to home*`